# How to hide or disable row cell if bool value is false?

Tags: jqgrid

I have jqgrid in which there are 4 col.

```js
{ name: "SaudId", index: "SaudId", editable: false, hidden:true},
{ name: "SaudName", index: "SaudName", editable: true },
{ name: "IsActive", index: "IsActive", editable: true },
{ name: "DoFlip", index: "DoFlip", editable: true },
```

I want if "IsActive" is false then DoFlip will not show or disabled.How Can i do this?

```js
{
    name: "DoFlip",
    align: "center",
    sortable: false,
    title: false,
    fixed: true,
    search: false,
    formatter: function (cellValue, options, rowObject) {
        debugger;
        var markup = "<a title=\"%ToolTip%\" href=%Href%;>%Text%</a>";
        var replacements = {
            "%Text%": "<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>",
          //
        };
        markup = markup.replace(/%\w+%/g, function (all) {
            return replacements[all];
        });
        return markup;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is **inside of** the column `DoFlip`? One can't disable text fragment, but one can disable `<input>` control for example. Hiding of cell have no sense too, but you can hide *the content* of the cell it it is wrapped inside of some element (inside of `<span>` for example). Which version of jqGrid and which fork you use? Free jqGrid for example can wrap the content of the column inside of `<span>` is `autoResizable: true` is defined in `colModel`. Alternatively you can use custom formatter.

Comment: DoFlip is icon like <i class='fa fa-pencil'>

Comment: <i class='fa fa-pencil'>  is inside the DoFlip

Comment: **Which version of jqGrid and which fork you use?** How come `<i class='fa fa-pencil'>` is inside the DoFlip? How you fill the grid? Typically one would use custom formatter in the column, but `colModel` which you use don't have any custom formatter.

Comment: Jqgrid version is 4.4.4

Comment: I am using froamtter and make html markup that return <i>

Comment: Which `datatype` you use? How you fill the grid? Could you include the corresponding JavaScript code? Why you use the retro version 4.4.4? Is it really required?

Comment: I added the in the question please check it.

Answer (score 1):

You use custom formatter for the column `DoFlip`. The custom formatter contains `options` and `rowObject` parameters. If you would use free jqGrid 4.9.2 instead of retro version jqGrid 4.4.4 the you could just use `rowData` property of `options` parameter to access parsed input data for the row. So you can use `options.rowData.IsActive` to access the value from `IsActive` of the input data. The format of `options.rowData` is not depends from the usage of `loadonce: true` option and it's the same for all values of `datatype` parameter of jqGrid (`"xml"`, `"json"`, `"local"` or other).

If you have to use jqGrid 4.4.4 then you will have to use `rowObject` which contains the input data *in the same format which you use*. It could be some specifics depend ob whether you use XML, JSON or object (`datatype: "local"`) of input data and whether input data are in format `repeatitems: true` or not. Additionally it's important whether you use `loadonce: true` or not. In any way `rowObject.IsActive` or something like `rowObject[2]` or `rowObject.IsActive !== undefined ? rowObject.IsActive : rowObject[2]` could provide you the required data.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to take ID of row.

```
var ids = $mygrid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
```

then in loop you need to

```
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                  var rowID = i + 1;
                  var mycolumValue = $("#" + rowID + "_myfirstcolumn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}

//here myfirstcolumn is first column in jqgrid
```